# How do i refresh the session in comet?

Tags: php, jquery, session, comet

I want to have a comet-like iframe on my page, but when the session changes the info in the iframe does **not** and i did a dump of the `$_SESSION` variable in the iframe and it was not changing.

My question is, how do i update the `$_SESSION` variable in the comet iframe when the client `$_SESSION` changes?

Thanks so much ^_^

**update with code:**

client:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])) $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Comet</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test_function(msg){

            $('p').html(msg)

        }

        $('div').click(clickMe);

        function clickMe(event){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'addSess.php'
            })
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>This is a test</p>
      <div>click me</div>
    <iframe src="output.php" width="0" height="0" style="display: none;"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

comet iframe (output.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
echo 'hello';
flush_buffers();
while(true){

    echo "<script>window.parent.test_function('".time().' session: '.$_SESSION['count']."');</script>";

    flush_buffers();

    sleep(1);


}

function flush_buffers(){
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    ob_start();
}
?>
```

addSess.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])) $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
$_SESSION['count']++;


echo $_SESSION['count'];
?>
```

also another thing i noticed is that its freezing up the browser from going to my site, as soon as i close the client, everything else loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you make changes to the `$_SESSION`, all reloads to the iframe that does `var_dump($_SESSION);` should see the new session. Are you properly using [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)?

Update with some code please and we'll see how we can help.

**UPDATE**

First off, your comet page needs `set_time_limit(0);` so it runs indefinitely (the connection can still get cut off and you'd need to do something to restart the comet connection)

Second off, output buffering might be giving you errors, PHP is wonky in that sense, my local test doesn't work with your code because of it. If I add the line:

```
<iframe src="output.php" width="0" height="0" style="display: none;" onload="alert('Iframe Loaded');"></iframe>
```

I get the alert at the same time as the update to the main page, meaning flush buffers failed to actually flush buffers. I'll return when I get the code working here.

**UPDATE2**

Sigh. Simplicity...

```
$('div').click(clickMe);
```

Needs to be called after the HTML DOM loads. try:

```
$(function(){
    $('div').click(clickMe);
});
```

Also you should consider changing your comet code to this:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
echo 'hello';
while(true){
    echo "<script>window.parent.test_function('".time().' session: '.$_SESSION['count']."');</script>";
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

By doing [ob_implicit_flush](http://ob_implicit_flus) you don't need to call flush_buffers constantly. You also need ob_end_flush to cancel output buffering.

You should also take note that [session_destroy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) is needed. Otherwise your site waits for the comet session to close before it can start a new session.

The way session_start() actually works, is it waits for the session to become available. This means you need to use [session_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) to generate a different session for your comet or use files... or employ some other technique.

Comment: Well there are a couple of things wrong :-? Updating* my post.

Comment: @Khez. the thing is i see the time() updates on the client side, but not the session. and it slowwws down any other load from my site

Comment: @Khez, ur second update still doesnt work, yes it registeres the click now, but the session display number does not change, and im still having an issue with other pages loading

Comment: It's due to the way session_start() works. Check my updated post. You can't have 2 pages with the same session_id call session_start(); You have 2 different tabs on the webserver one has to finish so the other can start.

Comment: @Khez so can u show me how to use session_destoy and session_id in my implementation?

Comment: Well a highly unoptimized way to do it would be to do session_destroy(); before every sleep(1); To give time for other pages to load, but this means that your comet will wait for other pages to load. Hmz, either you open up another question or I make a new answer here :-? kinda outside the scope of your original question and this answer.

Comment: Touche. Although it's still your question :x Nevermind, making a new post.

Comment: We should move to a chat room :-? Your main problem is that the session is not meant to be used like this, have you tried using a database or files ?

Comment: @Khez i have my own chat site on my profile which might be easier

Comment: Yes, woups, closed your chat.

Comment: @Khez, can u go back to it? ^_^

Comment: @Khez, thank you for all your help ^_^ switched over to using files instead of sessions

Comment: I knew you'd see it my way! :) Glad to help, feel free to ask more stuff of me and SO in the future.

Comment: @Khez, i just put up my new question ^_^