# How do i get session without calling session_start

Tags: php, class, session, comet

I right now have a comet page, that if i call `session_start` at the top then the session freezes, my work-around that do is this:

```
function getTables($sessionID = null){

        if(!isset($this->output)){
            $this->output = array();
        }

        if(!isset($this->output[$this->sessID])){
            $this->output[$this->sessID] = array();
        }
        $hostname = php_uname("n");

        $sess_ini = session_save_path();
        chdir($sess_ini);
        if(false === ($save = @file_get_contents("sess_$this->sessID"))){
            $cwd = getcwd();
            chdir($this->location);
            return (isset($this->returnJSON[$this->sessID])?$this->returnJSON[$this->sessID]
                    :json_encode(array(
                        'sess_local'=>"$sess_ini/sess_$this->sessID",
                        'save'=>$save,
                        'hostname'=>$hostname,
                        'cwd'=>$cwd,
                        'reg_local'=>$this->location,
                        )
                    )
                );
        }
        chdir($this->location);
        //session_id($sessionID);
        $sessions = explode("|",$save);
        $_SESSION['all'] = array();
        foreach($sessions as $key=>$sess){
            if(trim($sess)=='all' && isset($sessions[$key+1])){
                $_SESSION['all'] = unserialize(trim(urldecode($sessions[$key+1])));
                break;
            }
        }
        ...
```

Is there a better way for me to be getting the session vars thats **not** going into the session files?

Comment: I think you need to address and solve the root problem (why `session_start()` makes things freeze) instead

Comment: @James C that was a prev question of mine.... and it was solved by removing the session_start from the comet infinite frame -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553830/how-do-i-refresh-the-session-in-comet

Comment: @James, this was due to the fact that there are limitation in php with having two sessions present with the same id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work around can be much simpler:

```
 <?php
 //yes, start normally.
 session_start();

 //now, immediately harvest the variables you need to remember from the $_SESSION
 $somevar_you_want_to_remember = $_SESSION['somevar'];

 //close the session, so it won't lock:
 session_write_close();

 //disable some errors which aren't really errors:
 ini_set('session.use_cookies',false);
 session_cache_limiter(false);

 //you are now free to do anything you like:
 while(true){

     echo "<script>window.parent.test_function('".time().' sessionvar: '.$somevar_you_want_to_remember."');</script>";

     flush_buffers();
     sleep(1);
     //if you need to refresh your variable, you can just reopen the session:
     session_start();
     $somevar_you_want_to_remember = $_SESSION['somevar'];
     //and immediately close again
     session_write_close();         
}
```

You could write some helper functions, like:

```
 function SaveQuickSessionVar($name,$value){
      session_start();
      $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
     session_write_close();     
 }

 function GetQuickSessionVar($name){
     session_start();
     $var = $_SESSION[$name];
     session_write_close(); 
     return $var;    
 }
```

Comment: this seems to be working ^_^ i never knew about `session_write_close`

Comment: i am getting this warning:`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/live_mockup/comet/output.php:63) in /var/www/html/live_mockup/comet/output.php on line 56`  but i guess it does not matter?

Comment: Every second should be no problem, and although it complains about headers being sent, you can safely ignore that because the reason it needs that (sending cookie with id) has already succeeded. Although, ignoring warnings might not be 100% 'clean', it can be done with good reason, but I'll see if I can find a warning-less solution.

Comment: kk. for now i just put `error_reporting(0)` at the top to not show the warnings, but a non-warning solution would be nice

Comment: Ack, testing here reveals that a `ini_set('session.use_cookies',false);session_cache_limiter( FALSE );` _after_ the first `session_write_close()` does the trick.

Comment: See the edit in my code, it will remove the warnings (they will not be there instead of being ignored :) )

Comment: yepp that seemed to work, thanks ^_^ what exactly does that new snippet do?

Comment: It effectively disables the 2 portions of vanilla session-handling that require headers to be sent: first is session-cookies, which require a cookie header, and the second one is the cache header (public, nocache, etc.) which disables caching of the output as it is session-dependent. Both of those headers will have been sent the first time you call `session_start`, but it's not clever enough to figure that our, so by disabling it after the first call to `session_start` it will not complain about not being able te send headers that have actually already been sent the first time around.

Answer (score 3):

PHP's default session handler locks the session file while it's in use by a script. Comet keeps the handler script active for long periods, which keeps the session locked. You can work around it by doing

```
session_start();
session_write_close();
```

in your Comet script. It'll populate $_SESSION with the stored data, and then close the session file and relinquish the lock on it. The data in $_SESSION will still be present and usable, and you can even change it. The only difference is that unless you do a subsequent `session_start()` in your script, those changes will not be written out to the on-disk session file.

So, you CAN use regular PHP sessions in your script, you just have to take care that any long-running sections have the session closed before that section starts executing.